Почему некорректно работает параметр маршрутизатора Razor Pages?
Только учусь, возникла ошибка, хочу услышать вашего совета. Вроде сделал всё как по образцу, но при переходе на страницу всегда выводится 0 :(
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;

namespace WebApplication1.Pages
{
    public class FeedbackModel : PageModel
    {
        public int _pageId { get; set; }

        /*public bool? _feedbackStatus { get; set; } = null;

        public string _feedbackResponce { get; set; } = "";

        [BindProperty(Name = "feedbackEmail")]
        private string _feedbackEmail { get; set; } = "";
        
        [BindProperty(Name = "feedbackTextarea")]
        private string _feedbackTextarea { get; set; } = "";*/

        public void OnGet(int pageId)
        {
            _pageId = pageId;
        }

        public void OnPost()
        {
            /*_feedbackStatus = true;
            _feedbackResponce = "Обращение успешно отправлено";*/
        }
    }
}


@page "{id=1}"
@model FeedbackModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Обратная связь";
}

<p>Номер страницы: @Model._pageId</p>


Ну как бы 0 это значение по умолчанию для int переменной. А цель какая? Или Вы передаёте GET-запросом pageId=42, а на странице выводится 0? Или как? Добавьте больше информации в Ваш вопрос...

Только что проверил - у меня работает. Ввожу адрес так: http://localhost:5073/?pageid=234. Как вы проверяли?

@XelaNimed, разобрался в чём конкретно у меня проблема. Я указываю id и в OnGet ловлю pageId, поэтому 0 и выводится
